# Unable to generate access token for linkedIn

Tags: javascript, node.js

`Console.log(code)` is working fine but after that I am getting the error:

> {"error":"invalid_redirect_uri","error_description":"Unable to retrieve access
>   token: appid/redirect uri/code verifier does not match authorization code. Or authorization code expired. Or external member binding exists"}.

```
`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.set("view engine","ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));


app.get('/home',function(req,res){
    res.render('home');
})

app.get('/profile',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.query.code);
    var code = req.query.code;
    request.post({url:'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken', 
    form: 
    {grant_type:'authorization_code',code:code, 
    redirect_uri:'http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Fprofile', 
    client_id:'value', client_secret:'value'}}, 
    function(err,httpResponse,body){ console.log(httpResponse.body); })`
})
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I see `code:'$code'` but maybe it has to be :

```
code:`${code}`
```

And your redirect_uri points to a localhost, maybe thats the problem.

Comment: I saw this post https://naveengopisetty.wordpress.com/2014/09/15/linkedin-oauth-2-0-issue-invalid-redirect_uri-this-value-must-match-a-url-registered-with-the-api-key/ saying linkedin add extra value to its redirect_uri : /signin-linkedin